# kartik fileinput error in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I installed kartik fileinput via composer and successfully installed!
but when im used that like:

```
   use yii\helpers\Url;
   use yii\helpers\Html;
   use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
   use kartik\widgets\FileInput;

  echo FileInput::widget([
    'name' => 'attachment_48[]',
    'options' => [
        'multiple' => true
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/site/file-upload']),
        'uploadExtraData' => [
            'album_id' => 20,
            'cat_id' => 'Nature'
        ],
        'maxFileCount' => 10
    ]
]);
```

in backend part, i get error :

```
Class 'kartik\widgets\FileInput' not found
```

what's wrong with my code?
Any help appreciated!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this..........

```
use kartik\file\FileInput;
```

Comment: Do you know why it is like this?

Comment: @Amir Because `namespace kartik\file` is present in `FileInput.php`.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I'm having the same problem, installed the widget with composer. I have tried 3 different `use` statements that are on Kartiks page and none of them working. Anyone have any ideas?